# Google Forms Time Field Not Showing AM/PM on some mobile devices

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, mobile, google-forms

On desktop, only chrome displays the field correctly. on Mobile, it is chrome also, but it displays it correctly sometimes but most of the time, it is a no go. Tried on smartphones and tablets, iOs and Android, no windows phone lol.

Comment: I would guess that the timestamp is a 24 hour so there is no am/pm

Comment: All devices were set to 12 hour format

Comment: I doubt that we can be of much help.  Sometimes it works.  Sometimes it doesn't.  We primarily are interested in fixing codes issues.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I will have to hope

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used military time with response sheet formatting to solve the issue

Comment: yet you dont say how to set military/24 hour time in Google Forms

Comment: You should have marked Mr Shane's answer as the accepted answer, not your own, which is really not your own answer but that of Mr Shane. That it how this forum works.

Answer (score 2):

##### EDITED to reflect further research provided by @WeAreOne.

A combination of choice of browser and language settings in a users Google account will determine how date and time answers are formatted (on user by user basis) in Google Forms.

**How to change language settings:**

1. Go to Language Settings
2. Add a language that uses your prefered time format
3. Make the language preferred by clicking the arrow on the right side of the langauge, until it is at the top.

**Examples of each type:**

**12 hour AM/PM**

- English - Canada
- English - United States (PC Firefox and Chrome, Mobile Chrome)
- German (Non-incognito Chrome on PC and Mobile)

**24 hour military**

- Balinese - Indonesia
- Basa Sunda - Indonesia
- English - Australia
- English - India
- English - New Zealand
- English - Singapore
- English - United Arab Emirates
- English - United Kingdom
- English - United States (PC all browsers using Incognito, Edge, Mobile Firefox)
- German (All browsers except non-incognito Chrome on PC and Mobile)
- Indonesian - Indonesia
- Jawa - Indonesia

Comment: Changed to English US. Now I have 24h i all incognito browser windows and in Edge. am/pm in Firefox and Chrome. In phone Crome am/pm, in phone Firefox 24 h. I guess you are right, but the browsers seems to handle it differently. When I change it to German language (which is 24 h) it is 24 h style on all browsers except non incognito Chrome on PC and Mobile.

Comment: With German language all Date formats are the same and right, only the time in Chrome is wrong (am/pm)

Comment: Tested the forms from the different browsers. Even though the time fields display differently, the times comes correctly into the google sheet. So it doesn't matter how the time field is displayed. Answer gets right. Also I tried to send "13:30 AM" and it came right (13:30:00) in google sheets. So we don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @WeAreOne thank you for the extra research. This is all very helpful for folks wondering how to get the desired format style for date/time "questions" on Google Forms.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your Google account language is set to English United States.

Comment: Is this a description of how to apply the existing, well researched, better explained answer, which covers much more than a single case, to your specific case? Or the specific case of the question? I perceive that as little more than "Thanks", which is considered a non-answer and tends to be deleted. Can you [edit] to make more obvioud which additional insight you contribute?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).